# Ansible: Read variables from properties file

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to translate some shell scripts to ansible playbooks. 
In the shell scripts there are a lot of variables that are read from a separate properties file in which these variables are defined. 
Is there some module or some other way that I can do this. For example,
if in the properties file I have 
$WORKDIR=/opt/app defined and in the ansible playbook I want to call some module for example, 
copy:
  src: /tmp/app
  dest: $WORKDIR/

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Have a look at this article on how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

Use `lookup` ([doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_lookups.html#the-ini-file-lookup))

Example:
`{{ lookup('ini', 'user.name type=properties file=user.properties') }}`

- `user.name`, property key you want to read
- `user.properties`, property file you want to read from

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in ansible the inventory is the file where we define the hostname or ips along with variables.

Whenever we execute ansible playbook we pass a file using --inventory inventory ----> this is the default way of passing an inventory file

The playbook will source this file and all the variables defined inside it can be used.

In ansible the variable substitution happens using {{ WORKDIR }}

There are other ways of passing variable to playbook.

Such as
-- include_vars
-- using roles 
-- defining vars inside playbook.
-- extra vars